# C# Linq to SQL:cannot add an entity that already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq for Insert,Delete and update the database in my code.
While inserting data using InsertOnSubmit, I Am getting the  `cannot add an entity that already exists` Exception.
Please have a look my code

```
private static void AddNewPriceSettings(PRICE_SETTING priceSettingsInfo)
{
   PRICE_SETTING priceSetting = new PRICE_SETTING();
   priceSetting = priceSettingsInfo;           
   DataContext.CommonUsers.PRICE_SETTINGs.InsertOnSubmit(priceSettingsInfo);          
   DataContext.CommonUsers.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the properties for the new priceSetting.

```
private static void AddNewPriceSettings(PRICE_SETTING priceSettingsInfo)
{
   PRICE_SETTING priceSetting = new PRICE_SETTING();
   //
   priceSetting.Prop1 = priceSettingsInfo.Prop1;
   priceSetting.Prop2 = priceSettingsInfo.Prop2;
   priceSetting.Prop3 = priceSettingsInfo.Prop3;
   // ...
   DataContext.CommonUsers.PRICE_SETTINGs.InsertOnSubmit(priceSetting );          
   DataContext.CommonUsers.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: by the way, you should use InsertOnSubmit(priceSetting); instead of InsertOnSubmit(priceSettingsInfo);

Comment: Yes and thank you very much. it is working after including primary keys value.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `AddNewPriceSettings()` using an existing `PRICE_SETTING` object, you're indeed trying to add it again. The second line in your method does that. The `new PRICE_SETTING();` you create on the first line is then not referenced to anymore and will be GC'ed without trying to insert it.

If you want to create a copy, you'll have to clone the `priceSettingsInfo` into the `priceSetting` variable (you can use various techniques for that) prior to inserting and submitting it.

Comment: Could you please tell me about clone?

Comment: @user1063573 could you please show some effort? The easiest way perhaps is to create a [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
cannot add an entity that already exists
```

The problem is clearly stated by the error message. You already have a row in your database that contains the same entity as the one you are trying to insert.

How does SQL decide if two items are "the same"? It uses a key column, which usually is an integer id.

So that leads me to ask you - how does your column definitions look for the affected table? And where are you getting the `PRICE_SETTING` that is passed into the method?

The problem could also be that you are trying to perform an **update** on an already existing object - in that case you need to use different methods. Please share more info regarding the context.

Comment: I already deleted the previous data and i have filled new PRICE_SETTING data after deleting the old data.

Comment: Instead of updating the data . I have deleted old data and tried to insert new data.